# didExitRegion not being called, loops didEnterRegion

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, region, clregion

I am fairly new to iOS Development and I am trying to create an App that allows region monitoring. Similar to that of the iOS Reminders App.

I have my code to the point where I am starting monitoring for regions and it should notify me when I enter and leave a region. However, it only tells me when I am in the region. When I leave, it does not tell me.

Just so you know, I am testing this on my iPhone and definitely went outside of the 100m radius (I drove my car for 10 minutes away from my house). It kept looping messages saying I was in the region but never changed when I exited the region. I am really stumped as to where I am going wrong. Can anyone help? Also, just out of curiosity, as I am new to iOS development, am I going about this the correct way? Or is there a more efficient way of accomplishing this? Any advise, tutorials, howto's would be very much appreciated. Thanks guys! My code to start the region monitoring and methods are below. Let me know if you need any other code.

```
(IBAction)addRegion:(id)sender {
    if ([CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {
        // Create a new region based on the center of the map view.
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, _mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude);
        region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:coord
                                           radius:Radius
                                       identifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", _mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, _mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude]];


        // Start monitoring the newly created region.
        [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region];
    }
    else {
     NSLog(@"Region monitoring is not available.");
    }
}

(IBAction)stopMonitoringRegion:(id)sender {
   [_locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region];
}

(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)reg {

   if (state == CLRegionStateInside) {
       //call didEnterRegion
       //[_locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
       [self locationManager:_locationManager didEnterRegion:region];
   }
   if (state == CLRegionStateOutside) {
       //call didExitRegion
       //[_locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
       [self locationManager:_locationManager didExitRegion:region];
   }
}

(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
}


(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

//requestStateForRegion
if (region == nil) {
    //do nothing
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation %@ from %@", newLocation, oldLocation);
}else{
[_locationManager requestStateForRegion:region];
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation %@ from %@", newLocation, oldLocation);
}
}


(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region  {
    NSLog(@"didEnterRegion %@ at %@", region.identifier, [NSDate date]);
}


(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"didExitRegion %@ at %@", region.identifier, [NSDate date]);
}

(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"monitoringDidFailForRegion %@: %@ Error: %@", region.identifier, [NSDate date], error);
}
```